# Find from two columns of first dataframe into the second dataframe into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

One is this:

```
col1 col2 col3
43    21   2
32    31   4
```

and second

```
cl4 cl5 cl6
43   1  "text"
21   0  "text2"
32   1  "text3"
```

From dataframe 1 the value of col1 and col2 exist in cl4 of the second dataframe.

How is it possible to create a condition in which take the values of col1 and col2 from dataframe 1 and find in cl4 of dataframe 2 and based on this condition take the values of cl6

Example

```
df1.col1 == df2.cl4 && df1.col2 == df2.cl4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
print (df2)
   cl4  cl5    cl6
0   43    1   text
1   21    0  text2
2   31    1  text3
3   32    4  text4

#shift column for test next row
df2['a'] = df2['cl4'].shift(-1)
#join together next cl6 value
df2['new'] = df2['cl6'] + ', ' + df2['cl6'].shift(-1)
#remove last row of Dataframe because NaN
df2 = df2.iloc[:-1]

#create list of sets by actual and nex values
df2_sets = [set(x) for x in zip(df2['cl4'], df2['a'].astype(int))]
df1_sets = [set(x) for x in zip(df1['col1'], df1['col2'])]
#compare values and at least one True return True
#filter by boolena indexing
s = df2.loc[[any(x == y for y in df1_sets) for x in df2_sets], 'new']
print (s)
0     text, text2
2    text3, text4
Name: new, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you. and after identification, I can take the values cl6?

Comment: You can use `s = df['cl6']`

Comment: I am sorry jezrael I just tested it but it doesn't work. Maybe the query wasn't helpful to understand the problem. The first step is that for the first df the two columns has a combination. I want to check according to this combination into the second dataframe which has one column if this combination exist in this one column. When it will find it give the result of the text column

Comment: @Pozmanski - So you think `df1.col1 == df2.cl4 AND df1.col2 == df2.cl4`? Or `df1.col1 == df2.cl4 OR df1.col2 == df2.cl4` ? Because if AND then need `df1.col1 == df2.cl4  == df1.col2` ?

Comment: Let me provide a simple example. df1.col1 = 43 and df1.col2 = 21 lets say. In df2 I want to find in the same time df1.col1 == df2.cl4 = 43 and df1.col2 == df2.cl4 = 21 which means detect the combination and according to this finding take the result of the two rows of the cl6

Comment: @Pozmanski - Yes, but I dont understand it - How is possible in same time - same row `col4` is `43` and `21` ?

Comment: @Pozmanski - But is possible in same time `col4` is `43` or `21`.

Comment: I want to detect them as combination

Comment: Do you think one row and next row of `col4` ?

Comment: Yes think like in the first data frame of two columns I have the required combination and the second data frame has a single column. Using as condition I want to create a new df in which I will extract the 43 and 21 values and the "text" and "text2" into a single row

Comment: @Pozmanski - thank you,  iunderstand now. It is more complicated, give me some time.

Comment: @Pozmanski - Is order important? If `col1=21` and `col2=43` need match first and second row too?